# How to limit query from the end. Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const messagesRef = collection(db, 'messages')
const q = query(messagesRef, orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'), limit(25))
```

Im querying documents in 'messages' collection by creation time, the problem with this is that when im trying to limit documents, it limits from the start, but i want to limit it from the end. I want that user would see newer messages but not the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last 25 items, use `limitToLast(25)` instead of `limit(25)`. While that function isn't mentioned in the guide on limiting data, you can find it in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#limittolast).